# Probability: Three balls are drawn from a bag containing $~4~$ white and $~6~$ black balls.

Tags: probability

Find the probability that:

$(a)\quad$ $3~$ balls drawn are all white

$(b)\quad$ just one is white

For both problems, I am unsure on where to start and how to approach the problem. How do I do these probability problems?

Comment: How many ways are there to draw three balls from a collection of ten balls? Those are the outcomes of the experiment. How many satisfy $a$? Divide that by the total outcomes to get the probability. You use the same method for $b$ or any other question about the probability of an outcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The total number of ways to draw $3$ of $10$ balls is $\binom{10}{3}=\frac{10!}{3!7!}=\frac{10\cdot 9\cdot 8}{3\cdot 2\cdot 1}=120$. That's your denominator. Your numerator for the first problem is the number of ways to draw $3$ of the $4$ white balls. Your numerator for the second one is the number of ways to draw $1$ of the $4$ white balls and $2$ of the $6$ black ones.

Does that help?